# i have a problem with initializing a 2D array in C using user input

Tags: c

i have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void set_board_size() {
    int Xsize, Ysize, check = 1;
    while (check == 1) {
        printf("enter X and Y sizes(in that order): ");
        scanf_s("%d", &Xsize);
        scanf_s("%d", &Ysize);
        if ((Ysize >= 4 && Ysize <= 9) || (Xsize >= 4 && Xsize <= 9)) {
            break;
        }
        else
            printf("---------");
    }
    int mat[Xsize][Ysize];
}
void main() {
    set_board_size();
}
```

on line

```
int mat[Xsize][Ysize];
```

it says i must use a constant value but how can i do that with user input?

Comment: Specify a C standard of C99 or later to make use of the *Variable Length Array* in your code. If I recall correctly, VS17 or later provides the ability to do so with `/std:c11` See [/std (Specify Language Standard Version)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/std-specify-language-standard-version?view=msvc-170) Unless you are programming in a *freestanding environment* (without the benefit of any OS), in a standards conforming implementation, the allowable declarations for `main` for are `int main (void)` and `int main (int argc, char *argv[])`

Comment: You don't allow values greater than 9. Just make it 9x9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
int** mat = (int**)malloc(Xsize * sizeof(int*));
for (size_t i = 0; i < Xsize; i++)
{
    mat[i] = (int*)malloc(Ysize * sizeof(int));
}
```

And don't forget to deallocate everything when you're done using it:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < Xsize; i++)
{
    free(mat[i]);
}
free(mat);
```

You will probably need to change this:

```
int Xsize, Ysize;
```

To this:

```
size_t Xsize, Ysize;
```

And this:

```
scanf_s("%d", &Xsize);
scanf_s("%d", &Ysize);
```

To this:

```
scanf_s("%zu", &Xsize);
scanf_s("%zu", &Ysize);
```

Comment: You should explain that there is no array involved in what you are doing. You should further mention that compiling with the standard set to C99 or later will allow the OP's code to take advantage of a VLA (*Variable Length Array*) as it is written. Given the use of `scanf_s()` the OP is likely compiling on a Microsoft compiler that for C defaults to C89 -- prior to the introduction of VLAs.